# How do I change the default mapping for Emoji Text Replacement in Messages on OSX?

Tags: macos, keyboard, messages

I like that Messages uses text replacement to change `:)` into an emoji. However, I hate the default mappings. I want to change the emoji that is mapped to those text replacement strings.

For example, `:)` currently gets replaced by . But I would prefer to it be . Similarly, `:(` gets replaced by , but I would prefer .

Aside from creating my own text replacements in `System preferences > Keyboard > Text`, is there a way to change this? I don't want to enable a universal text replacement because I sometimes use text emoticons in applications that don't support emojis.